# IIS WCF Service shuts down with domain user identity

Tags: wcf, iis, service, dns

I am currently working on my very first WCF Web Service, with hosting in IIS 8.5. I am currently running into a problem.

If I use ApplicationPoolIdentity, the service runs at least. I can check the service in a browser and view the WSDL. If I change the identity in IIS to a domain user, the service shuts down when requestet. I need it to run with some privileges, since the service works with our Active Directory.

My Webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode ="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="net.hasuma.webservices.portalx.AdfsService">
        <endpoint address="" contract="net.hasuma.webservices.portalx.IAdfsService" 
                  bindingNamespace="net.hasuma.webservices.portalx" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration ="TransportSecurity"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>    
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I know what is the issue to shut it down (Identity), but I have no clue why this is happening. I asume something is wrong with my webconfig.

As always there are some restrains. The service can write on the AD directory, so only SSL allowed.

Comment: I've seen this happen frequently when there is a problem with domain account (usually an invalid password).  Are you able to log into the resource with that domain account?

Comment: @Tim Yes, this my current domain account (for testing). It works if I run the webservice local with IIS-Express over Visual Studio, since it runs it with my current user without questions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am officially stupid. I am testing on a VM with Windows Server and I didn't joined the AD. The domain user was not know, so the service shuts down. I am sorry to bother you with my stupidity.